# Adding copyright info on each photo using iPhoto

Tags: photos.app

Is it possible to add copyright information, or a logo, on the pictures themselves (bottom right corner for instance) for a selection of photos, at once, using iPhoto ?

If iPhoto is not the right app to do it, what would be a free tool to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to use an application such as [ExifShopper](http://www.macupdate.com/download/27845/download.php?id=4), which allows you view/edit image Exif information; It's free and also let's you do batch jobs. I wouldn't recommend iPhoto for doing this, people have complained quite often about it corrupting Exif data, etc.

If you're looking to watermark your images try [iWatermark](http://www.plumamazing.com/mac/iwatermark/).

Comment: Yes I want to add something ON the picture itself, not editing the info tags. (That's why I mentionned Bottom-left)

Comment: Then you'll definitely want to use a watermarking application, or if you're not concerned with it being removed you could use just about any graphics application to overlay text on your images; if you want to do it in batch you could even do this with terminal commands, applescript, or with automator.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an app that makes it very well; I let the information here for future readers. it's called [JetPhoto Studio](http://www.jetphotosoft.com/web/home/). And there is free lite version that allows watermarking.

Comment: I'm glad you found something that works. That application looks decent too; I'll have to try it out.

Comment: Yes, indeed, I was amazed that some companies try to compete on the field of app that are given by Apple. I've never look to an alternative to iPhoto, but indeed this app seems really powerful and well designed.